# Sqoop import throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException where class refers to table name

Tags: java, hadoop, sqoop

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I built a Hadoop server with a sample database in MySql Server which has an `orders` table.

I'm using Sqoop to generate an `import` with the following command:

`sqoop import --table orders --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels --username hadoop -password 1234 --target-dir /BigData/Sample/Orders/myBirthdayOrders.txt --where "orderDate = '2003-02-17'" --bindir ./libjars`

I'm using `libjars` root directory to save Hadoop generated classes but after run the previous command, I got the following error:

```
Java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:270)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:266)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:528)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)
```

But the generated classes is in the `libjars` directory:

[libjars directory content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugZjV.png)

This is the whole command log:

```
hadoop@HadoopMaster:~$ sqoop import --table orders --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/classicmodels --username hadoop -password 1234 --target-dir /BigData/Sample/Orders/myBirthdayOrders.txt --where "orderDate = '2003-02-17'" --outdir ./libjars --bindir ./libjars

Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.

Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.

Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.

Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.

2023-03-12 18:55:18,249 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7

2023-03-12 18:55:18,335 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.

2023-03-12 18:55:18,476 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Preparing to use a MySQL streaming resultset.

2023-03-12 18:55:18,476 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation

Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.

2023-03-12 18:55:19,283 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `orders` AS t LIMIT 1

2023-03-12 18:55:19,393 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM `orders` AS t LIMIT 1

2023-03-12 18:55:19,405 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/local/hadoop

Note: ./libjars/orders.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

2023-03-12 18:55:21,371 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: ./libjars/orders.jar

2023-03-12 18:55:21,385 WARN manager.MySQLManager: It looks like you are importing from mysql.

2023-03-12 18:55:21,386 WARN manager.MySQLManager: This transfer can be faster! Use the --direct

2023-03-12 18:55:21,386 WARN manager.MySQLManager: option to exercise a MySQL-specific fast path.

2023-03-12 18:55:21,386 INFO manager.MySQLManager: Setting zero DATETIME behavior to convertToNull (mysql)

2023-03-12 18:55:21,390 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of orders

2023-03-12 18:55:21,391 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address

2023-03-12 18:55:21,518 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar

2023-03-12 18:55:22,083 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps

2023-03-12 18:55:22,199 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties

2023-03-12 18:55:22,310 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).

2023-03-12 18:55:22,310 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: JobTracker metrics system started

2023-03-12 18:55:22,640 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation

2023-03-12 18:55:22,720 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1

2023-03-12 18:55:22,973 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local1418369330_0001

2023-03-12 18:55:22,974 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []

2023-03-12 18:55:23,316 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Creating symlink: /tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/job_local1418369330_0001_e15ca564-f245-408f-925d-501daf15ec63/libjars <- /home/hadoop/libjars/*

2023-03-12 18:55:23,325 INFO mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized file:/tmp/hadoop/mapred/staging/hadoop1418369330/.staging/job_local1418369330_0001/libjars as file:/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/mapred/local/job_local1418369330_0001_e15ca564-f245-408f-925d-501daf15ec63/libjars

2023-03-12 18:55:23,476 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/

2023-03-12 18:55:23,483 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null

2023-03-12 18:55:23,488 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local1418369330_0001

2023-03-12 18:55:23,547 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2

2023-03-12 18:55:23,547 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false

2023-03-12 18:55:23,550 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter

2023-03-12 18:55:23,701 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks

2023-03-12 18:55:23,702 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1418369330_0001_m_000000_0

2023-03-12 18:55:23,772 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 2

2023-03-12 18:55:23,779 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: FileOutputCommitter skip cleanup _temporary folders under output directory:false, ignore cleanup failures: false

2023-03-12 18:55:23,856 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]

2023-03-12 18:55:23,899 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation

2023-03-12 18:55:23,901 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: 1=1 AND 1=1

2023-03-12 18:55:23,935 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.

2023-03-12 18:55:23,988 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1418369330_0001

java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:552)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2688)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getInputClass(DBConfiguration.java:403)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DataDrivenDBInputFormat.createDBRecordReader(DataDrivenDBInputFormat.java:270)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.createRecordReader(DBInputFormat.java:266)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.<init>(MapTask.java:528)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:348)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:271)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)

    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class orders not found

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2592)

    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2686)

    ... 12 more

2023-03-12 18:55:24,547 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1418369330_0001 running in uber mode : false

2023-03-12 18:55:24,548 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%

2023-03-12 18:55:24,551 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1418369330_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA

2023-03-12 18:55:24,556 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0

2023-03-12 18:55:24,560 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead

2023-03-12 18:55:24,561 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 2.4241 seconds (0 bytes/sec)

2023-03-12 18:55:24,561 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead

2023-03-12 18:55:24,561 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.

2023-03-12 18:55:24,562 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed
```

!

Comment: Sqoop is a retired Apache Project. Are you required to use it? Spark is more commonly used to read JDBC tables into HDFS nowadays

Comment: And not really clear how you created this libjars folder, but you should try using Maven/Gradle instead. Classes probably cannot be imported from the default package (show your orders class, please)